# iOS Navigation Bar icons issue

Tags: ios, icons, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have a question regarding iOS user interface guidelines and Navigation Bars: I'd like to display some icons just to let users be aware of some parameters' status. Those icons appearance may change according to such status. I've reading the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW52) documentation regarding Navigation Bars and it looks like its icons are expected to be buttons the user could touch to trigger some action. Would the app be rejected when submiting to the Apple Store if icons in Navigation Bar are only for user information?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the Submission guidelines as Apple changes it often! Assuming you have a developer account, here is the link https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html